# Sentence editing C++

Tags: c++, string, char

I'm new to programing and i have to make a program in which you enter a sentence and remove any  repeating characters like space, commas and so on. So my idea was to print only the characters that match my criteria. But i get a problem like this :

input : "This is(5 spaces for example) a (2 spaces)  sample  (3spaces)sentence".

but the output is :"This",instead of "This is a sample sentence"

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int const l=200;
int main ()
{
    char a[l];
    cin >> a;

    int d;

    d=strlen (a);

    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < d; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] != ' ' && a[i+1] != ' ')
        {
            cout<<a[i];
        }
    }
}
```

It would be nice if you tell me what my mistake is and how to solve it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `#include <string>` and [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Comment: ...Aaaaaand indent your code. And use `std::size_t` for sizes.

Comment: BTW, your problem is that `std::istream::operator>>` only inputs until it encounters some whitespace. Don't use it. Use `std::cin.getline()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using `cin` will consider each space separated word as a single input and it will store only `this` as a single string is provided. Use `cin.getline()` instead of `cin` to get input with spaces.

```
char a[l];
cin.getline(a, l);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this condition here:

```
 if(a[i]!=' ' && a[i+1]!=' ')
```

When the program reaches the last space (which is the one you want to keep), it will fail the `a[i] != ' '` condition and skip the character.  What you want is:

```
 !(a[i] == ' ' && a[i+1] == ' ')
```

Comment: This is only part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have slightly modified your code for removing running spaces . You can edit for removing commas also. Use std:: string and getline function for reading strings as >> reads only till a space. I hope this helps.

```
#include<cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int const l=200;
int main() {
        string a;
        getline(cin,a);
        int d;
        d=a.size();
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < d; i++) {
                if(a[i]==' ') {
                        cout<<" ";
                        while(a[i]==' ')
                                ++i;
                }
                cout<<a[i];
        }
        cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Is that working? modifiying i inside the while inside the for loop does not seem a good practice for me.

Comment: It does work. In,fact modifying i makes it efficient as the running spaces are skipped and are not iterated twice. As soon as a[i] is not a space which is the end of the while loop , I print the character which ensures that none of the characters are missed.

Comment: 'while(a[i]==' ') ++i' is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Lets see

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string a;
    getline(cin, a);
    for(int i=0;i < a.length();i++)
    {
        if( i+1 < a.length())
        {
            bool whatIwant = !(a[i] == ' ' && a[i+1] == ' ');
            if(whatIwant){ cout<<a[i]; }
        }
        else { cout<<a[i]; }
    }
}
```

Not the better or efficiente way of doing it, but, this should do the job.
Tested, and working.

Notice that if not catching the i+1 condition properly you coult jump into memory trouble.

Comment: 'i < a.length()' is trouble

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.

The first one is that you use operator >> for entering the sentence. This operator enters only symbols beofre a white space. So when you enter

"This is a sample sentence"

the result of applying operator

```
cin >> a;
```

will be that array a will contain only word "This". Instead of this operator you should use function

```
cin.get( a, l );
```

The second problem is that the condition in the if statement is incorrect. Should be

```
    if ( a[i] != ' ' || a[i+1] != ' ' )
    {
        cout<<a[i];
    }
```

Also you can use standard algorithm std::unique_copy. For example

```
    std::unique_copy( a, a + std::strlen( s ), std::ostream_iterator<char>( std::cout ),
        []( char c1, char c2 ) { return ( c1 == ' ' && c1 == c2 ); } );
```